# Fail to position android popupwindow relative to its size (Android API8)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, popup

I want to position a popup window as a tooltip above another view + offset according to the popup size.

I have tried few ways unsuccessfully:

**1) Try 1 : using `showAtPosition()` twice.**

```
// The method that displays the popup.
  public void showPopup(View viewToPointAt) {

    this.mViewToPointAt = viewToPointAt;

    mPopUpView = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tooltip_share, null);
    mPopup =
        new PopupWindow(mPopUpView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

    mPopup.showAtLocation(mPopUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0); // Displaying popup


    ViewTreeObserver vto = mPopUpView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mPopUpView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);


    mArrowPoint = new Point();
    mPopupRect = locatePopup(mPopUpView);
    mArrowPoint.x = mPopupRect.right - DisplayUtils.dpiToPixels(10);
    mArrowPoint.y = mPopupRect.bottom;


    mRectToPointAt = locateView(mViewToPointAt);


        mPopUpView.bringToFront();
        mPopup.setFocusable(false);
        mPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);




    mPopup.showAtLocation(mPopUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,
 mRectToPointAt.right - mArrowPoint.x,
            mRectTo

PointAt.top - mArrowPoint.y); // Displaying popup

      }
    });

  }
```

result: the popup is still at (0,0)

**2) Try 2 : using `update(..)`**

```
// The method that displays the popup.
  public void showPopup(View viewToPointAt) {

    this.mViewToPointAt = viewToPointAt;

    mPopUpView = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tooltip_share, null);
    mPopup =
        new PopupWindow(mPopUpView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

    mPopup.showAtLocation(mPopUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0); // Displaying popup


    ViewTreeObserver vto = mPopUpView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mPopUpView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);


    mArrowPoint = new Point();
    mPopupRect = locatePopup(mPopUpView);
    mArrowPoint.x = mPopupRect.right - DisplayUtils.dpiToPixels(10);
    mArrowPoint.y = mPopupRect.bottom;


    mRectToPointAt = locateView(mViewToPointAt);


        mPopUpView.bringToFront();
        mPopup.setFocusable(false);
        mPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);


        mPopup.update(mViewToPointAt, 0, 0, -1, -1);

      }
    });

  }
```

result: the popup is aligned to the screen bottom. No matter how big the offset I give it

My tooltip_share.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tooltip_layout"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tip_tool_top_right"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tip_tool_icon_plane" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use below library :-

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.supertooltips

https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

Comment: I cannot use external libs in this project

Answer (score 0):

You have to create popup.xml as per your popup design ...after then you have to call popup whenever you want.

write code on Create :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

on Button Click :

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btn_share, 50, -30);
```

Comment: I'm using API8, and your initialization is similar to mine. no?